# How to use PHP to delete X number of lines from the beginning of a text file?

Tags: php, file, logging

I'm writing a PHP script and the script outputs a simple text file log of the operations it performs.  How would I use PHP to delete the first several lines from this file when it reaches a certain file size?

Ideally, I would like it to keep the first two lines (date/time created and blank) and start deleting from line 3 and delete X amount of lines.  I already know about the `filesize()` function, so I'll be using that to check the file size.

Example log text:

```
*** LOG FILE CREATED ON 2008-10-18 AT 03:06:29 ***

2008-10-18 @ 03:06:29  CREATED: gallery/thumbs
2008-10-18 @ 03:08:03  RENAMED: gallery/IMG_9423.JPG to gallery/IMG_9423.jpg
2008-10-18 @ 03:08:03  RENAMED: gallery/IMG_9188.JPG to gallery/IMG_9188.jpg
2008-10-18 @ 03:08:03  RENAMED: gallery/IMG_9236.JPG to gallery/IMG_9236.jpg
2008-10-18 @ 03:08:03  RENAMED: gallery/IMG_9228.JPG to gallery/IMG_9228.jpg
2008-10-18 @ 03:08:03  RENAMED: gallery/IMG_3104.JPG to gallery/IMG_3104.jpg
2008-10-18 @ 03:08:03  RENAMED: gallery/First dance02.JPG to gallery/First dance02.jpg
2008-10-18 @ 03:08:03  RENAMED: gallery/BandG02.JPG to gallery/BandG02.jpg
2008-10-18 @ 03:08:03  RENAMED: gallery/official03.JPG to gallery/official03.jpg
2008-10-18 @ 03:08:03  RENAMED: gallery/Wedding32.JPG to gallery/Wedding32.jpg
2008-10-18 @ 03:08:03  RENAMED: gallery/Gettaway car16.JPG to gallery/Gettaway car16.jpg
2008-10-18 @ 03:08:04  CREATED: gallery/thumbs/Afterparty05.jpg
2008-10-18 @ 03:08:04  CREATED: gallery/thumbs/IMG_9254.jpg
2008-10-18 @ 03:08:04  CREATED: gallery/thumbs/IMG_9175.jpg
2008-10-18 @ 03:08:04  CREATED: gallery/thumbs/official05.jpg
2008-10-18 @ 03:08:04  CREATED: gallery/thumbs/First dance01.jpg
2008-10-18 @ 03:08:04  CREATED: gallery/thumbs/Wedding29.jpg
2008-10-18 @ 03:08:04  CREATED: gallery/thumbs/men walking.jpg
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$x_amount_of_lines = 30;
$log = 'path/to/log.txt';
if (filesize($log) >= $max_size)) {
  $file = file($log);
  $line = $file[0];
  $file = array_splice($file, 2, $x_amount_of_lines);
  $file = array_splice($file, 0, 0, array($line, "\n")); // put the first line back in
  ...
}
```

edit:
with correction from by rcar and saving the first line.

Comment: You'll probably want > $max_size rather than ==

Answer (score 22):

### Use the SPL, Luke

PHP 5 comes with plenty of iterators goodness :

```
<?php

$line_to_strip = 5;
$new_file = new SplFileObject('test2.log', 'w');

foreach (new LimitIterator(new SplFileObject('test.log'), $line_to_strip) as $line)
    $new_file->fwrite($line);    

?>
```

It's cleaner that what you can do while messing with fopen, it does not hold the entire file in memory, only one line at a time, and you can plug it and reuse the pattern anywhere since it's full OO.

Comment: This solution writes to a new file, but the question asked about editing a file.

Answer (score 4):

This is a text-book problem of log files, and I would like to propose another solution.

The problem with the "removing lines at the beginning of files" approach is that adding new lines becomes extremly slow, once it has to remove the first lines for every new lines it's writing.

Normal log file appending only involves writing a few more bytes at the end of the file in the file system (and once in a while it has to allocate a new sector, which results in extensive fragmentation - why log files usually are).

But the big problem here is when you are removing a line in the beginning for every row written. The entire file must first be read into memory and then rewritten resulting in huge ammount of I/O to the harddrive (in comparision). To make matters worse, the "split into PHP array and skip first rows" solutions here are extremly slow due to the nature of PHP arrays. This is not a problem if the log file size limit is very small or if it is written to unoften, but with a lot of writes (as in the case with log files), the same huge operation has to be done a lot of times resulting in major performance drawbacks.

This can be imagined as parking cars on a line with space for 50. Parking the first 50 cars is quick, just drive in behind the car infront and done. But when you come to 50, and the car at the front (beginning of file) must be removed you have to drive the 2'nd car to the 1'st position, 3rd to 2nd and so on, before you can drive in with the last car on the 50'th position. (And this must be repeated for *every* new car you want to park!)

My suggestion is instead saving to diffrent log files, datewise, and then store a maximum of 30 days back etc. Thus taking advantage of the filesystem, which has already solved this problem perfectly well.

Comment: Fantastic idea, but for my particular needs, this is unacceptable.  I have a small log file, that probably wont be written to much/often.  But I'll keep this in mind for future projects.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [file()](http://php.net/file) function to read the file into an array of lines, then use [array_slice()](http://php.net/array_slice) to remove the first X lines.

```
$X = 100; // Number of lines to remove

$lines = file('log.txt');
$first_line = $lines[0];
$lines = array_slice($lines, $X + 2);
$lines = array_merge(array($first_line, "\n"), $lines);

// Write to file
$file = fopen('log.txt', 'w');
fwrite($file, implode('', $lines));
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a ready to go function

```
<?php
//--------------------------------
// FUNCTION TO TRUNCATE LOG FILES
//--------------------------------
function trim_log_to_length($path,$numHeaderRows,$numRowsToKeep){
    $file = file($path);
    $headerRows = array_slice($file,0,$numHeaderRows);
    // if this file is long enough were we should be truncating it
    if(count($file) - $numRowsToKeep > $numHeaderRows){
        // figure out the rows we wanna keep
        $dataRowsToKeep = array_slice($file,count($file)-$numRowsToKeep,$numRowsToKeep);
        // write the file
        $newFileRows = array_merge($headerRows,$dataRowsToKeep);
        file_put_contents($path, implode($newFileRows));
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typical operating systems don't provide the capability to insert or delete content of a file "in-place". What you will need to do is write a function that reads the first file, and creates a *new* output file containing the lines you want to keep. Then when you're done, delete the old file and rename the new one to the old name.

In pseudocode:

```
open original file IN for reading
create new output file OUT
read the first two lines from IN
write these lines to OUT
for each line to skip:
    read a line from IN
for the remainder of the file:
    read a line from IN
    write the line to OUT
close IN
close OUT
delete IN
rename OUT to IN
```

The advantage of this method over some of the other ones presented is that it *doesn't* require you to read the whole file into memory first. You didn't mention how large your upper size limit was, but if it's something like 100 MB you might find that loading the file into memory is not an acceptable use of space.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run a linux command, try `split`. It allows you to split by line count to make things easy.

Otherwise, I'm thinking you'll have to read it in and write to 2 other files.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to [@Greg's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215896/how-to-use-php-to-delete-x-number-of-lines-from-the-beginning-of-a-text-file#215898) answer, you can read-in the entire file into an array, skip the first X many entries, then rewrite the array to the file.

As an approach: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

```
$fle = file_get_contents("filename");
// skip X many newlines, overwriting the contents of the string with ""
// https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php
file_put_contents("filename", $fle);
```

Comment: The problem with this is then, depending on how many lines is written, the dates/times will be out of order.  Also, I foresee the file writing to the same lines over and over.

Comment: Yes, that could be an issue (writing the same data repeatedly), depending on how large the file is - this is certainly a brute-force method :)  .. why would date/times be out of order? unless during the read in php the file was appended-to, I don't think you would see that

Answer (score 0):

following code will help you to delete the number of lines from beginning of a file

```
$content = file('file.txt');
array_splice($content, 0, 5); // this line will delete first 5 lines //change asper your requirement  
file_put_contents('file.txt', $content);
```