# replace first 23 lines of file with string containing 10 lines php

Tags: php, file, replace, fwrite

I want to remove the first 23 lines from the beginning of a file and replace them with a string containing 10 lines, e.g.

```
$newstring = "line1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10";
```

What's the easiest way to go about it? I've been playing around with `fwrite`, but I'm definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215896/how-to-use-php-to-delete-x-number-of-lines-from-the-beginning-of-a-text-file

Comment: The last thing I tried was removing the blank lines with preg_replace then writing in 10 lines of text and 13 blank lines with $txtw=fopen('txt.txt','r');
fwrite($txtw,$newstring);
fclose($txtw);

Comment: 23 lines or characters? `from the beginning of a file` - which type of file?

Comment: lines - the files is .xml but it's basically a .txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
replace_first_lines_in_file('path/to/file.txt', 23, $new_string);


function replace_first_lines_in_file( $file_path, $num_lines, $new_string )
{

    $file = file_get_contents($file_path);
    if( ! $file )
        return false;

    $pattern = '#^([^\n]*\n){' . $num_lines . '}#si';
    $new_file = preg_replace($pattern, $newstring, $file);

    if( ! file_put_contents($file_path, $new_file) )
        return false;

    return true;

}
```

Comment: thanks, but i'd like to write to the same file i'm reading - can you file_put_contents to the file you're reading from?

Comment: Yes. You read from it. Then you write to it - it's 2 separate operations. You're not reading and writing at the same time.

Comment: @John Edited as per your comment.

Comment: Wrapped in a function for you as I'm waiting for a build.

Comment: thanks! by the way, $new_file, $file_path should be $file_path, $new_file - also, it seems to replace every line in the file with my string repeated :S

Comment: @John fixed those 2 issues now :)