# How to 'recycle' unused file-space in storage architecture?

Tags: php, arrays, file-io, storage

I have a file-system that stores a key-value array in a storage file, using php.

When a new key-pair is added/removed to the storage, the file is opened for appending at the end of the file. if an existing storage array exists in the file (i.e the cursor is not at 0), that array is read and re-written with the new key-pair appended/removed. The existing array is not read into memory, its read sequentially per key-pair at the same time as the new array is written next to it.

The problem I'm facing is that after say 4 writes, the file will have 3 unused blocks of space. But I want to "re-use" that space in future writes. I'm just unsure how that would work.

There is a good answer to a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215896/how-to-use-php-to-delete-x-number-of-lines-from-the-beginning-of-a-text-file), which explains that with php you can't truncate from-to (e.g from byte 0 to byte 20), equating to writing to a temporary file when adding a new key-pair, and then renaming the temporary file to the existing one when finished. Eliminating any free space altogether.

This would be costly through and make write times much slower, which is important in my situation.

Just to clarify, the existing architecture looks like this on writes

```
open file for appending
check if existing data in file
IF existing data
    while read existing key/value
        if existing key === new key : value = new value
        if value === null : continue; 
        write key/value
    close file
ELSE
   write key/value
   close file
```

What would be an appropriate method to "re-use" the unused(obsolete) file-space without effecting performance too-much? Something in pseudocode would be nice.